# How to launch the Calculator through Terminal

Tags: command-line, calculator

I use the default Ubuntu calculator rather a lot, but to use it I have to use the Unity search feature to find it and then open it. I have tried to open it in Terminal with:

```
calculator
```

And:

```
Calculator
```

But neither of those seem to launch, so how do I launch the calculator through Terminal? What command do I use? Also, as my Unity Dock is rather full, it's not really an option just to put a link to it there.

Comment: BTW, you should check out some alternatives to the simple Gnome calculator which run _in_ the terminal. `dc` is the classic, and in some ways similar to a desktop calculator... but IMO that's not really good workflow; I'd recommend the REPL of a modern functional language like `python` or Haskell (`ghci`). Those can do anything a traditional calculator can, plus much, much more.

Comment: Or: you can [calculate stuff right in the shell](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/)!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try to type:

```
gnome-calculator
```

Or for Older version (Ubuntu 12.04 and before):

```
gcalctool
```

Comment: gcalctool won't work

Comment: @Pilot6 you're right, i just modify it :)

Comment: `$ galculator` should work. the c is replaced by g. Don't type gc...

Answer (score 22):

Always when you have such a question in mind, ie, you don't know the name of the tool to invoke it in command line, find it from the terminal itself:

```
man -k <keyword>
```

It will search the manual page names and descriptions for the `keyword` you specified and prints the titles. In your case, it would be:

```
man -k calculator
```

As an illustration, if you want to invoke the webcam tool you can type something like:

```
man -k camera
```

`man -k` is equivalent to `apropos`.

Comment: This is a vastly better answer than the accepted answer.  It teaches "how now" but also, briefly, digs into how to help "how later."

Answer (score 9):

[Qalculate!](http://qalculate.sourceforge.net/) is awesome tool for desktop.

To install it: `sudo apt-get install qalculate`. 
Terminal version `sudo apt-get install qalc`.

---

Converts currency:

```
 $ qalc 100 dollars to euro
 100 * dollar = approx. EUR 90.017103

 $ qalc 100AUD = x EUR
 (100 * dollar) = (x * euro) = approx. x = 90.017103
```

Works with percent:

```
 $ qalc 87.12 + 13.3%
 87.12 + (13.3 * procent) = 87.253
```

Gets Unix timestamps:

```
 $ qalc timestamp today
 timestamp("2015-08-14") = 1.4394996E9
```

Operates boolean:

```
 $ qalc true != false
 true != false = 1
```

Also you can do `ln -s /usr/bin/qalc /usr/bin/c` for shorthand:

```
 $ c "(2+2)*2"
 (2 + 2) * 2 = 8
```

Comment: `gnome-calculator` no longer works for me after adding some extensions to gnome, something to do with control of display (`MPFR assertion failed`...`core dump`) but this works perfectly, so nice one for that! It's also somewhat better than the default, so can't recommend enough.

Answer (score 6):

The command is `gnome-calculator`

Answer (score 2):

I created an alias for this in ~/.bash_aliases as follows

```
calc="gnome-calculator &"
```

save the file and then type the following in the terminal

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

You can now launch the calculator using `calc` in the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is about how to actually launch it. That is I was asking for its command-line name, so although your answer might actually be good as an additional edit, it's unhelpful and somewhat odd as a stand-alone answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the command below

```
xcalc
```